# Adding a custom field in log4j using SyslogAppender

Tags: java, logging, log4j, syslog, graylog2

I'm using the SyslogAppender in my java application and I'm trying to add a custom field to the resulting log. How can I add an additional field to my log4j.properties?

My current log4j.properties (the last line shows what I want to achieve):

```
log4j.appender.SYSLOG=org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.syslogHost=localhost
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.facility=LOCAL4
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.header=true
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.layout.conversionPattern=my-app: %m%n
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.applicationName=${STACKNAME}
```

The ${STACKNAME} is a system property configured by the deployment job, depending on the environment (e.g. prod, test, dev).

Answer (score 0):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35169384/5108777) I get the answer: add the lines

```
log4j.appender.graylog2.additionalFields={'filed_name': 'field_value', 'field2_name': 'field2_value'}
log4j.appender.graylog2.addExtendedInformation=true
```

to add `field_name` and `field2_name` with values `field_value` and `field2_value`. The property `addExtendedInformation=true` indicates Graylog to add those fields to all log entries.